# Laravel - use Request in a function that call another function

Tags: laravel, request.querystring

I need to retrieve also query string params after registration, so I'm using Request $request in both functions, but how I can pass Request also in second function?

thanks in advance!

```php
protected function create(Request $request, array $data) // added "Request $request" for retreive querystring params
{
    $user->name = $data['name'];
    $user->surname = $data['surname'];
    $utm_source = $request->query('utm_source');
    
    $user->save();
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all()))); // here I'll need two pass two params...

    return $this->registered($request, $user) ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: You pass `request` as $request only, $request->all() will give you an array not request object, so if you have to pass request pass `$request` and in calling function you can perform `$request->all()`.

Comment: `$this->create($request, $request->all())` ?

Comment: @IGP Already tried this solution, I get this error: Trying to get property 'surname' of non-object

Comment: @Prashant Deshmukh Sorry I not understand your solution :(

Comment: Yes, bcs `$user` is not defined in `create()` ... ?  Looks like you are just confusing yourself trying to inline everything.  Take an extra line or 2, make your code more readable, close this as a typo :-)

Comment: The other option I can think of is 1) remove `Request $request` from create function and get query params with `request()->query('utm_source')`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Since you have used hinting for the `$request` param inside the `create` method it has to be an instance of the `Request` class.

`Request::class` and `$request->all()` are different so passing `$request->all()` will not work.

```
protected function create(Request $request)
{
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->surname = $request->surname;
    $utm_source = $request->query('utm_source');
    
    $user->save();
}

public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request)));

    return $this->registered($request, $user) ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: I resolved with another simple way, adding hidden input with parameters like this {{ app('request')->input('utm_source') }}, and retreive it like others fields of form, but your solution is perfect for other causes. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Laravels` container binding only works on controller methods that are invoked, if you call it through ordinary `PHP` syntax, you will need to pass each parameter.

```
event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request, $request->all())));
```

Secondly you can anywhere in your app, use the container to get your request, as long as the lifecycle has a request off course (eg. not in jobs or commands).

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $request = resolve(Request::class);
```